XML TEI to HTML
I am trying to write a xsl file in order to transform a given xml to html (for publication). Here is my example xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.stoa.org/epidoc/schema/latest/tei-epidoc.rng" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
   <teiHeader>
    ...   
   </teiHeader>
   
    <text xml:lang="grc">
      <body>
         <div type="edition" n="urn:cts:greekLit:tlg0059.tlg010.perseus-grc2" xml:lang="grc">
            <div type="textpart" subtype="section" resp="perseus" n="11">
               <p>
                 <said who="#Σωκράτης">
                 <milestone  unit="page" resp="Stephanus" n="11"/>
                 <milestone unit="section" resp="Stephanus" n="11a"/>
                   <label>ΣΩ.</label> 
ὅρα δή, Πρώταρχε, τίνα λόγον μέλλεις παρὰ Φιλήβου δέχεσθαι νυνὶ καὶ πρὸς τίνα τὸν παρʼ ἡμῖν ἀμφισβητεῖν, <milestone unit="section" resp="Stephanus" n="11b"/> ἐὰν μή σοι κατὰ νοῦν ᾖ λεγόμενος. βούλει συγκεφαλαιωσώμεθα ἑκάτερον;
</said></p></div></div></body></text>


I would like to highlight labels in bold, and, ideally, to place milestone sections (like 11b) on the left margin along the text (but I have no idea how to embark on this latter task).
Here is a xsl I have written:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/HTML" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 
 <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="label">
    <b>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </b>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p">
    <p>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

But the output is plain text, no breaks and no bold. Any hint would be much appreciated!


The XML has been truncated and can not be used without us fixing it first. Please make it complete and correct. Also it wouldn't hurt to make it shorter (remove repetitive elements) and better formatted/indented.

Sorry for this, I have made necessary corrections
